# Combobox databinding showing system.data.datarowview

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-binding, combobox

I am binding combobox with datasource, displaymember, valuemember. It is working fine in my computer but it is not working in clients pc. Following is my source code:

cbxAlloyBinding method is called from the Constructor of the UserControl.

```
private void cbxAlloyBinding()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT alloyName,alloyId FROM alloy", con);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            cbxMetal.DisplayMember = "alloyName";
            cbxMetal.ValueMember = "alloyId";
            cbxMetal.DataSource = dt;
        }
        else
        {
            cbxMetal.Text = "";
        }
    }

    private void cbxMetal_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbxMetal.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            tempcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT specification,alloyCode FROM alloy where alloyId='" + cbxMetal.SelectedValue + "'", con);
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(tempcmd);
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txtSpecification.Text = dt.Rows[0]["alloyCode"].ToString();
                txtSupplyConditions.Text = dt.Rows[0]["specification"].ToString();
                cbxheatBinding();
            }
            else
            {
                txtSpecification.Text = "";
            }

        }
    }
```

This is bothering me from last two days and i almost tried all tricks but it is still not working.

Client's PC is using Windows 7 ultimate, sql server 2005 and .net framework 3.5.

Comment: i tried many other things  
1) making dataview and then passing it to datasource.
2) making dataset and then passing it to datasource.
3) Changing the position of datasource before displaymember and ValueMember, After displaymember and ValueMember, between both of them. 
But nothing seems to be working on the client pc.

Comment: Are you sure that you have privileges/rights to execute sql statements on the client pc?

Comment: Yes privileges/rights all set because same code is running fine on other Usercontrols. It is not working on this usercontrol only..

Comment: Is this all the code or are you doing something else coz i believe this should work

Comment: @V4Vendetta I have added the whole code in my question please look at it.

Comment: @SaralDoshi I know your post is old but one thing might be an issue .NET versioning on client. I have experienced similar issues - normally I set display and value member first - but in NET 3.5 I have the same condition you describe.

Answer (score 7):

setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMemeber` after setting the `DataSource` fixed this issue for me.

```
cbxMetal.DataSource = dt;
cbxMetal.DisplayMember = "alloyName";
cbxMetal.ValueMember = "alloyId";
```

Comment: Believe it or not, what fixed this for me was the exact OPPOSITE advise, which I found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/242834/ComboBox-selected-value-always-shows-system-data-d

I set the DataSource property AFTER setting the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties and my "System.Data.DataRowView" problem went away. This is such a weird bug. I also noticed, while debugging, that this problem was intermittent, making it extra hard to nail down.

Answer (score 6):

This definitely happens if your `cbxMetal_SelectedIndexChanged` is called before `cbxAlloyBinding()` is called in your constructor.

For instance (see the code below), you may have other combobox bindings in constructor which may come before `cbxAlloyBinding()` in constructor, and those bindings are calling `cbxMetal_SelectedIndexChanged`.

```
public Constructor()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        cbxheatBinding();      //1st Three Binding Methods may be somehow related to your cbxMetal,
        dtpStartDateBinding(); //which leads them to call cbxMetal_SelectedIndexChanged method.
        dtpEndDateBinding();
        cbxAlloyBinding();
}
```

What I suspect is your `cbxMetal.DataSource` is set from some other point in your code and well before `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` are assigned;

Just remember, `System.DataRow.DataRowView` will occur only if

> `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is called before `ValueMember` assignment.

Comment: you said 
System.DataRow.DataRowView will occur only if ComboBox.SelectedValue is called before ValueMember assignment.
I do not think that is an accurate statement as .
I do not set ComboBox.SelectedValue anywhere at all and I get this condition in a particular application (geared .NET 3.5) - in other apps it works fine. I am not sure why this happens but it appears that it is related to the datatable object and .NET versions , a list<T> seems ok.  - but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems problem is not with the code you pasted here, it may be with client environment, connection, privileges etc. You must give more info about that 'it is not working in clients pc'. What systems they use, what is the error, have you tried debugging in client side?

***Edit:***then you have to find the problem tracing all the operation from the beginning. My advice is that make a dummy windows form application, just a standard form, a combobox and a button. ON the click event of button just do what you did. JUst bind the combo and send this temp app to the client. If it works then do step by step.Ex:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conStr = "Data Source=PC-303\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=sokaklar;User ID=sa;Password=*****";

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT IL, IL_ID FROM sokaklar ORDER BY IL", new SqlConnection(conStr));
        DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);            

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "IL";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "IL_ID";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;            
    }
```

I created this app in one minute, and it is working for me.

Comment: the a On the display it is showing system.data.datarowview and not alloynames. Client is using windows 7 ultimate. What are the other things you like to know?

Comment: Could you please show all the code about combobox, changing properties, initializing its props? It seems that items, selecteditem edits conflict.

Comment: I am not changing any properties or initializing any of the properties. Apart from the above code I am only using its selected value in other functions.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved same this:

```
/*First get DataSource*/
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
/*Then determine DisplayMember y ValueMember*/ 
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "YOUR_FIELD_NAME";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "YOUR_OTHER_FIELD_NAME";
```

This only works with 
    System.Data.DataTable 
or 
    List 
data sources

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayMember'

Answer (score 0):

It was showing me the same exception, so I did this and it worked

```
    private void cb_category_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            DataTable mydt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                mydt = request.GetItem(int.Parse(cb_category.SelectedValue.ToString()));
            }
            catch { }

            if(mydt.Rows.Count>0)
            {
            cb_Item.DataSource = mydt;
            cb_Item.DisplayMember = "dispmember";
            cb_Item.ValueMember = "valmember";
            }
            else
            {
                cb_Item.DataSource = null;
            }       

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WILL DEFINITELY HELP TO YOU**

on the load Event you want to Just Write this code

```
onformload()
{
    cmb_dept.Items.Clear();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"DATA SOURCE=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;INTEGRATED SECURITY=true;INITIAL CATALOG=EMPLOYEE;");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select dept_id, dept_name from department", conn);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    cmb_dept.ValueMember = "dept_id";
    cmb_dept.DisplayMember = "dept_name";
    cmb_dept.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

try using Use the code where you want to access the values........

```
string dept = cmb_dept.Text;
MessageBox.Show("val=" + dept);
```

### YOUR combobox.text = System.Data.DataRowView Will be Solved ##

Answer (score 0):

reading the answer in this post tells me there are so many ways this bug can reveal itself, for me it was the following: I had the combobox bound exact like mentioned in the question, and it was working fine, I change the **Sorted property of the combobox to True** in the Designer and started getting datarowview thing in each item. After wasting a lot of time found out that Sorted property should be False for this to work as expected. Sorting has to be dont through the query you used to get the data.

Answer (score -1):

"comboBox1.SelectedValue" returns object and you want as string so convert it Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedValue) and then use

for example:

```
  tempcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT specification,alloyCode FROM alloy where alloyId='" + Convert.ToString(cbxMetal.SelectedValue) + "'", con);
```