# ComboBox showing System.Data.DataRowView after changing selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have been looking at all the other questions similar to this one and they just don't seem to help me with my particular problem.

I am using a Combobox with the following properties:

[image: Properties of said Combobox]

The purpose of the Combobox is simple, it is taking all the values of an unique column in a table, and present them as options. The column's name is "nim".

Upon initialization, the combobox loaded just fine:

[image: Perfectly fine combobox]

The problem occurs after I changed the selected item to the 2nd one in the list, and tried changing it again:

[image: Messed up]

When I tried selecting System.Data.DataRowView, this error appeared:
[image: An error]

I have been playing around with the code to no avails. I didn't write any code concerning the combobox. I just assign the DataSource, DisplayMember, and ValueMember from the properties window manually.

The only code concerning combobox is these:

```
private void comboNIM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //selectedNIM = ((DataRowView)comboNIM.SelectedItem).Row["nim"] as String;
        selectedNIM = comboNIM.SelectedValue.ToString();

    }
```

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: The error say that there is already a value 'System.Data.DataRowView' in your datasource. Post the code corresponding to "The problem occurs after I changed the selected item to the 2nd one in the list, and tried changing it " ,the problem is here and the error is clearly normal.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! 

The said table doesn't even have a record with 'System.Data.DataRowView' as the value of any of its column. 

I don't understand what do you mean by "code corresponding to ...", but the 'System.Data.DataRowView' options showed up at runtime, after I changed my selection from 1355301050 (Default) to 1355301051, and tried changing selection again.

Comment: Hi, and glad to help if I can ! I clearly supposed that there is no such value in your dataSource, that's why it's problematic ! It's a databind error or something like that, could you please post the code where the combobox is bind ? ( datasource databind....)

Comment: Umm, since I never really write any of the code to do the databinding (I just do it manually through the properties window), where can I find the code for that?

Comment: Possible useful link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14620545/combobox-databinding-showing-system-data-datarowview

Comment: I've read that thread, and I don't think it is the same situation as I am currently in. In that thread, the TC said that his clients got a problem, but not on his PC. And the problem doesn't suddenly occur at runtime (like mine). 

Anyway, I tried setting the DisplayMember, ValueMember and DataSource of the ComboBox programmatically in the form_load method. No success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So..., I have found a solution for this particular problem.

I deleted the ComboBox, and then created a new one. Then I just assign the properties programmatically.
`cb.DisplayMember = 'nim';
cb.ValueMember = 'nim';
cb.DataSource = mahasiswaBindingSource;`

Apparently, leaving the properties window unedited solved the problem!

Comment: Good ! So my link was a good start and hint :) Have a good day !